# Show html table content in separate boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple html page with a html table. I have complied the codes to show real time search result in the table format. I am just wondering if it is possible to show the table data in separate boxes? Like forms? I have 11 columns in My html table and few of them has very long data so text wrapping looks ugly.

Please guide me how can the data be filtered and displayed in scrollable boxes instead of normal table.

here is my code.

```js
  function myFunction1() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput1");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
        }       
      }
    }
    
    
 
 function myFunction2() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput2");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
        }       
      }
    }
```

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myTable tbody {
        height: 600px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
     
    }
     
    #myInput1 {
      background-image: url("res/searchicon.png");
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 26%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    #myInput2 {
      background-image: url("res/searchicon.png");
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 26%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font: 15px arial, sans-serif; 
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #eff1f4;
    }
    #myTable th, #myTable td {
      table-layout: fixed;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #DEC4BC;
    }
    
    
    img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="res/eGo.png" style="width:250px;height:150px;">
    
    <h2><font face="Arial" color="#c11919">eGO Web</font></h2>
    
    <input type="text" id="myInput1" onkeyup="myFunction1()" placeholder="Search for customer names" title="Type in a customer name">
    <input type="text" id="myInput2" onkeyup="myFunction2()" placeholder="Search for Customer Number" title="Type in a Customer Number">
    <br>
    <font size="2"face="Arial" color="#c11919">last updated on - July 2019</font>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <table id="myTable" style="display:visible;">
      <tr class="header">
    
        <th style="width:10%; ">Customer Name</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Account Number</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Collector Name</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Statement Email</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Customer Contacts</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Internal Contacts</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">3rd Party Payments</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Remarks/ Customer Profile</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Historical Activities</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Portal/ Invoicing Method</th>
     <th style="width:10%;">Statement Required</th>
      </tr>
    
    <--! Here is table data -->
    
    </table>
    <br>
    <font size="1"face="Arial" color="#c11919">To report issues <a href="mailto:pratik.kumar@company.com?Subject=Issue%20in%20Collector%20lookup%20tool%20" target="_top">Click Here</a> or send email to pratik.kumar@company.com</font>
   
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing as an answer as not allowed to comment yet. You could set the following styles:

```
    tr,td {
         overflow: auto;
}
```

> This will allow scrolling in cells of table when texts overflow or are more than specified size of boxes.

More on overflow here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: where to paste it? I am pasting it in css stye area as ```#myTable tr,td {
      overflow: auto;
}```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, table cells can contain another elements, and you can insert div with limited dimensions into  and set overflows for scrolling. For example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One cell</td>
    <td>second cell
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: auto">
        very long text goex here and scroll bar will appear
        very long text goex here and scroll bar will appear
        very long text goex here and scroll bar will appearvery long text goex here and scroll bar will appear
        very long text goex here and scroll bar will appear
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Third cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this is not exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for a layout which have 11 separate boxes and when I search anything in inputbox the data gets populated in those boxes. Without any additional database. Just html table saved in the same page.

Comment: I am facing another big problem with it. If that can be solved then probably it'll look better. Few of my 11 columns have very long data like urls. Even if I have used  ```table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;``` the column width is very wide (10th column). I have tried all possible fixes so far but didn't work.

Comment: You can use css text-overflow: ellipsis; to truncate long strings, or just let them go to new line if you set max-width? Maybe it would be better to use some table control? for example: [link](https://datatables.net/)